# Append to Existing Folder Name

Tags: python, file-rename

How would I go about adding to an existing folders/files name?
To clarify, I would like to add `"_working"` to an existing folder name (eg: mxd) to result in `mxd_existing`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
old_name = 'mxd'
new_name = old_name + '_working'
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Comment: [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

In case of renaming multiple directories within a single directory, you can make use of Python's [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join, isdir, abspath
from shutil import move

base_directory = "." # Directory in which we need to modify the dir names
base_directory = abspath(base_directory) # To make the base_directory an absolute path
# Above is needed for shutil.move to work

all_child_directories = next(walk(base_directory))[1]
for child_dir in all_child_directories:
    new_name = child_dir + "_working"
    if not isdir(join(base_directory, new_name)): 
    # shutil.move cannot move if the existing directory already exists
        move(join(base_directory, child_dir), join(base_directory, new_name))
```

This might look a lot but definitely not much. As given in the above link, os.walk will give a generator with the directory name, child directories and files within the directory as a tuple. Here we need only the second element of the tuple and so we choose [1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk). Now we just iterate over the list of child directories and move the entire directories with the new name.

Here, you can add any conditions that are to be met with the code. However, if you want only a few directories whose names are in patterns within a base directory with lots of child directories, you should look for [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module. This could get your job done quicker and simpler rather than iterating over all the files manually. LIke this:

```
from glob import glob
from shutil import move
from os.path import join, isdir, abspath

base_directory = "."
base_directory = abspath(base_directory)
pattern_name = "project" # part of the directory name
for dir_with_pattern in glob(join(base_directory, pattern_name)):
    new_name = dir_with_pattern + "_existing"
    if not isidr(new_name):
        move(dir_with_pattern, new_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this as a script in the folder you want to change:

```
import os
folder_name = os.getcwd() + "_working"
os.rename(os.getcwd(), folder_name)
```

If you get a permission denied error, that means you shouldn't be changing the name of the folder you're in, but if you really want to change the name, run the script using sudo python

Comment: This sounds like the solution but I should have added previously that I am trying to rename several of these folders to "_working" and they are subfolders within a main folder. I attempted to use listdir to list the folders within the folder and  rename.os(destination,desintation+"_working") but that gave me an error. Insight?